# converting all words in a file into * using sed in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I used the following command:

```
$ cat * | sed  's/./*/g' | head -50
```

But this code converts the blank spaces into `*` as well. I don't want that.

Example:

```
Hi my name is Mark
I am a good guy
```

Expected:

```
** ** **** ** ****
* ** * **** ***
```

Comment: That's not really programming, but ... `echo 'Hi my name is Mark I am a good guy' | sed 's/[^ ]/*/g'
** ** **** ** **** * ** * **** ***`

Comment: Same thing using `tr`; `echo 'Hi my name is Mark I am a good guy' | tr '[:graph:]' '*'`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but rather usage of sed. This should be on https://unix.stackexchange.com/  or  https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: @tink - presuming this question isn't closed, how about writing up an answer with your two suggestions. This is a borderline question on whether it is programming (correct use of regex) or shell "How do I use `sed`?" So it needs an answer if not closed.

Answer (score 0):

See David C. Rankin's comment above...

This can be achieved with `sed` with reasonable ease:

```
echo 'Hi my name is Mark I am a good guy' | sed 's/[^ ]/*/g' 
** ** **** ** **** * ** * **** ***
```

Or with `tr`:

```
echo 'Hi my name is Mark I am a good guy' | tr '[:graph:]' '*'
** ** **** ** **** * ** * **** ***
```